# Typoscript: Constants in value section

Tags: constants, typoscript

I've a object with some HTML code. I want to use a constant inside. My code is the following:

```
15 = TEXT
15 {
    data = getenv : TYPO3_SITE_URL
    wrap (
        <a href="https://www.xing.com/spi/shares/new?url={data}" target="_blank"><div class="c-menu-share__item social-xing"></div></a>

        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={data}" target="_blank"><div class="c-menu-share__item social-linkedin"></div></a>

        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={data}" target="_blank"><div class="c-menu-share__item social-facebook"></div></a>

        <a href="mailto:?body={data}" target="_blank"><div class="c-menu-share__item social-email"></div></a>
    )
}
15.outerWrap = <div class="c-menu-share">|</div>
```

That doesn't work. Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can´t use 'data' as a variable, but you can get your environment variable via `{getIndpEnv : TYPO3_SITE_URL}` (or `{getIndpEnv : TYPO3_REQUEST_URL}` if you want the url of the current page) directly. Try this:

```
15 = TEXT
15.value (
    <a href="https://www.xing.com/spi/shares/new?url={getIndpEnv : TYPO3_SITE_URL} " target="_blank"><div class="c-menu-share__item social-xing"></div></a>
    <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={getIndpEnv : TYPO3_SITE_URL} " target="_blank"><div class="c-menu-share__item social-linkedin"></div></a>
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u={getIndpEnv : TYPO3_SITE_URL} " target="_blank"><div class="c-menu-share__item social-facebook"></div></a>
    <a href="mailto:?body={getIndpEnv : TYPO3_SITE_URL} " target="_blank"><div class="c-menu-share__item social-email"></div></a>
)
15.insertData = 1
```